# jasmine, $q is undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner

I'm going through some of the examples online for AngularJS to try to understand how it works.  I'm trying to use jasmine to test like in the examples.  In my spec file, I have:

```
var Person = function (name, $log) {
    this.eat = function (food) {
        $log.info(name + " is eating delicious " + food);
    };
    this.beHungry = function (reason) {
        $log.warn(name + " hungry " + reason);
    };
};

var bob = new Person();

describe("describe", function () {
    it("$q", function () {
        var pizzaOrderFulfillment = $q.defer();
        var pizzaDelivered = pizzaOrderFulfillment.promise;

        pizzaDelivered.then(bob.eat, bob.beHungry);

        pizzaOrderFulfillment.resolve("resolved");
        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect($log.TypeInfo.logs).toContain(["resolved"]);
    });
});
```

I get

> ReferenceError: $q is not defined

Am I using Jasmine correctly? I basically am just writing all my angular and jasmine code in the spec.js file.  When I had the angular code in another file, my spec.js file couldn't find it.  Probably because I didn't set any dependencies up on what gets loaded first since I'm just starting out with this stuff.

Edit, fixed the $ to be $q and the referencerror.

Comment: Don't you want `$q.defer()` instead of `$.defer()`?

Comment: @Jonathan Ah yes, but I still get an error, $q is not defined.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you are not injecting the `$q` service in your unit test.

For example in your beforeEach block you can inject it:

```
var q;
beforeEach(inject(function($q) {
    q = $q;
}));
```

And then in your unit test:

```
describe("describe", function () {
    it("$q", function () {
        var pizzaOrderFulfillment = q.defer();
        var pizzaDelivered = pizzaOrderFulfillment.promise;

        pizzaDelivered.then(bob.eat, bob.beHungry);

        pizzaOrderFulfillment.resolve("resolved");
        $rootScope.$digest();

        expect($log.TypeInfo.logs).toContain(["resolved"]);
    });
});
```

Comment: How come you need to inject the $q service and not the $log?

Comment: Maybe you already injected it? I don't know the content of the rest of your file.

Comment: What I copied and pasted was the whole file.  If I had to inject anything, I did not know.  Just starting out and the book I'm going through doesn't list all the code.  Just snippets so I copied and pasted the snippets.

Comment: If you are reading Mastering Web Application Development with AngularJS you should have a link to download all the code examples.